# wxToolbar works on Mac but image is scrunched up on Windows

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a wxWidgets app that runs on Mac and Windows. I use images for the tool buttons and the image sizes are around 48x48. At the end of the tools I have a stretchable space and then another tool button which has the company logo. This image is 75x40. On Mac this image appears correctly but on Windows image size is reduced to around 48x48 and looks terrible.

I can set the image size using wxToolbar::setToolBitmapSize, but this size is applied to all the tools. Is there a way I can set individual tool bitmap sizes? Or is there any other way I can fix this problem on Windows?

TIA

Comment: what is your wx version? What Windows version you are testing under? IIRC, on Windows all buttons has to be the same size - the toolbar on Windows used to be an image list where all tools needs to be the same.

Comment: Also, are you using SVG or PNG/XPM?

Comment: wxWidgets ver 3.2.2.1, Windows 10 Pro. All my images are .PNG.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows all toolbar buttons have the same size. You can, however, put a custom control that can have a different size in the toolbar too, as shown in the "toolbar" sample included with wxWidgets. So the simplest solution would probably be to put a `wxButton` using your bitmap in the toolbar (but it won't look quite the same as the other tools).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using two toolbars, one for the tools and one just for the logo. Images in both toolbars have the same height, but the image in the 2nd toolbar with the logo has a different width